# checked table row should open in BOOTSTRAP MODAL

Tags: php, ajax

I have a database MySQL. We having personal details HTML table with radio button. I want to modify the table data using AJAX and PHP. After radio button is checked click modify button then checked table row should open in BOOTSTRAP MODAL. It is retrieving value from table, but its not showing in MODAL.i need a code after AJAX get success MODAL should open but here Modal is not working FOrm only displaying
        Two Files:

Two Files:
1)  modify.php

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modifyModal" id="emp_modify">Modify</button> 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'modify1.php', 
        data: {option:'modify',empID:id},
        success: function (data) {   //after AJAX get succes MOdal SHould open
        //$('#emp_modify1').html(data); 
        $("#getCode").html(data);
                $("#getCodeModal").modal('show');                               
        }
          });//end of ajax
            }
            else {
                alert("Select a row first");
            }
        })
        });
        </script>  

    </body>
```

2)  modify1.php

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="edit" name="edit">
   <div class="form-group">
   <input id="id" name="edit" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $elements['emp_id']; ?>"
</div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="form-field-1"> Name </label>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="uid" name="edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $elements['name']; ?>">
      </div>
</div> 
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="form-field-1">gender</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
  <input id="semail" name="edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $elements['gender']; ?>">
     </div>
</div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="form-field-1">gender </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input id="semail" name="edit" class="form-control" type="text"      value="<?php echo $elements['gender']; ?>">
       </div>
       </div>
       </form>
```

Comment: What are you getting after ajax response? And may you share rest of the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the full html elements in modify1.php

```
echo '<form class="form-horizontal" id="edit" name="edit">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="id" name="edit" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="' . $elements['emp_id'] . '"
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="form-field-1"> Name </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="uid" name="edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . $elements['name'] . '">
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="form-field-1">gender</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="semail" name="edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="' . $elements['gender'] . '">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="form-field-1">gender </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="semail" name="edit" class="form-control" type="text"      value="' . $elements['gender'] . '">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>';
```